# DisplayName return null in Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using email and password for sign up and sign in with firebaseAuth. When iam access displayName in signUp fragment, displayName return null, but in signIn fragment, displayName not returning null. This is my code :

**AuthRemoteDataSource**

```
class AuthRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(private val auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    suspend fun signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) : FirebaseUser{
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await().user!!
        }
    }

    suspend fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) : FirebaseUser{
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await().user!!
        }
    }

}
```

**UserManageDataSource**

```
class UserManageDataSource @Inject constructor(private val auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    fun getUser() : FirebaseUser{
        return auth.currentUser!!
    }

suspend fun setProfile(data: UserProfile.ProfileAuth) {
        val profile = userProfileChangeRequest { displayName = data.name }

        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){

            getUser().updateProfile(profile).await()

            Log.e("BUG", "setProfile: ${getUser().displayName}", )
            //auth.currentUser.reload()
        }
    }
```

when I try to test the displayName on the UserManageDataSource class in the code snippet `Log.e("BUG", "setProfile: ${getUser().displayName}", )`, displayName does not return null.

but when I try to call displayName on the signUp fragment in the code `Log.e("DEBUG", "handleUserCreated: $users.displayName", )`, my displayName returns null.

**SignUpFragment**

```
registerViewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    when(it){
        is UIState.Loading -> {binding.progressIndicator.show()}
        is UIState.Success -> {
            binding.progressIndicator.hide()
            toast(it.data.first)

            // Get user 
            val users: FirebaseUser = it.data.second
            // create user profile
            registerViewModel.createProfileAuth(
            UserProfile.ProfileAuth(
              name = getName())
            )

          Log.e("DEBUG", "handleUserCreated: $users.displayName", )

        }
        is UIState.Error -> {
            binding.progressIndicator.hide()
            toast(it.message)
        }
    }
})
```

i have try reload() but not working for me.